# CircuitPython on Raspberry Pi 4 (Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS)

Tags: python, raspberrypi

I am running a Raspberry Pi 4 with Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 . Since I am using a lot of Adafruit Parts for my setup it would be a lot easier to use CircuitPython (their offspin off of micropython) with their already created drivers and tutorials. Do you know if this is possible and if I have to adapt anything?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, there is https://learn.adafruit.com/building-circuitpython/linux, so I conclude that it is indeed possible. "Adapt anything" seems too vague to be answerable. Read the CircuitPython documentation.